# Interpolating data for two different time stamps in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have gas concentrations from 2 different instruments that ran simultaneously, so their time stamps are different, but during the same 2 hour block (for instance, O3 has 710 measurement points, but CO2 has 2190):

[image: data example]

I need a way to average or interpolate co2 concentrations that fall in between the o3 time stamps, so the arrays have the same number of points, and I can generate a scatter plot. I'm using python here. Is there a way to do this using scipy or numpy interpolate features?

I'm pretty new to coding and python (only about 1 month experience), so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Note that it's much more convenient for people trying to help you if you post text rather than images -- text, we can copy and paste to reproduce the same inputs, but with an image someone would have to type it all in manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scipy.interp.interp1d tool. Depending on what kind of interpolation you want, you can add "kind = 'cubic'" as a keyword argument to the interp1d function.

```
import scipy.interp as interp
import numpy as np

f_o3  = interp.interp1d(o3_time,  o3_conc)
f_co2 = interp.interp1d(co2_time, co2_conc)

new_time = np.linspace(start_time,stop_time,num_points)
new_o3 = f_o3(new_time)
new_co2 = f_co2(new_time)
```